# How to run asynchronous script in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller, lets say 'Foo' controller with function 'index' that takes a long time to execute.

I have a another controller, 'Bar' controller in which i want to process / call the 'index' function in the 'Foo' controller asynchronously.

```
class BarController extends \BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        // call the Foo controller here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call the 'index' function in the 'Foo' controller asynchronously?

Comment: You have a lot of options here. I think the best one is: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is exactly what [Laravel Queues](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) are for. Move your command into a library somewhere, and call a method to 'queue' the command. Then it will be executed while your original controller can return to the user.